# How to avoid escaping single quotes in JSX attribute

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jsx

I'm using nextjs build to create production build, but it's escaping single quotes in jsx attribute which I want to avoid.

Here is my image tag

```
<Image src={utils.getAssetUrl("/images/hero-image.svg")} />
```

`utils.getAssetUrl`

```
(url) => {
  return process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? url : `{{ get_asset_url('${url}') }}`;
}
```

This results in

```
<img src="{{ get_asset_url(&#x27;/images/hero-image.svg&#x27;) }}" />
```

while I want it to result in

```
<img src="{{ get_asset_url('/images/hero-image.svg') }}" />
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The `next/image` component is most likely escaping those characters internally. Out of curiosity, why do you want to pass a string in that format to `next/image`'s `src` prop?

Comment: I'm deploying it on HubSpot CMS which requires it this way. Anything within `{{ }}` is replaced with absolute path of the asset

Comment: I'm afraid `next/image` needs to know the path to the asset at build time for it to work and apply its image optimisations. You should probably use the `<img>` element instead.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Single quotes around `${url}`, `url` is already a string

```
(url) => {
  return process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? url : `{{ get_asset_url(${url}) }}`;
}
```

Comment: this results in `<img src="{{ get_asset_url(/images/hero-image.svg) }}" />`, which is not what I want

Comment: Try adding backslash before quote, ``{{ get_asset_url(\'${url}\') }}``

Comment: Tried both `\\` and `\\\`, didn't work